# using variables in a jython list wsadmin websphere

Tags: scripting, websphere, jython, wsadmin

I am trying to include a variable in my jython script to hold my nodename, but I end up getting `BSFEXception`. My script is this :

```
node=AdminControl.getNode()
AdminTask.installBusinessSpaceWidgets('[-nodeName %node% -serverName server1 -widgets C:/package/widgets/Widgets.zip]')
```

While I could do this with jacl, I couldn't find a way to do it in jython - which is what most of my scripts are written in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
node=AdminControl.getNode()
AdminTask.installBusinessSpaceWidgets('[-nodeName %s -serverName server1 -widgets C:/package/widgets/Widgets.zip]' % node)
```

Using a real list can be more convenient sometimes:

```
node=AdminControl.getNode()
AdminTask.installBusinessSpaceWidgets(['-nodeName', node, '-serverName', 'server1', '-widgets', 'C:/package/widgets/Widgets.zip'])
```